# Rearrangement of string conditionally?

Tags: python

I have spent the last 2 months working on a script that cleans, formats, and geocodes addresses. It is quite successful right now, however, there are some addresses that are giving me problems.

For example:

Addresses such as `7TH AVENUE 530 xxxxxxxxxxx` are causing my geolocation module to fail. You can assume that the x's are other text. The other text isn't causing errors, it's purely due to the street number coming after avenue. I currently have filters in my program to truncate the address after street suffixes, such as avenue, street, etc. Due to this the program will ultimately only send `7th avenue` to the cleaning module, which isn't accurate.

How can I account for instances where there are a group of numbers immediately preceding the street suffix and then move them to the front of the address. Then I can continue as I already am and truncate the string after the suffix.

You can assume that I have a list of all of the street suffixes named `patterns`.

Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated.

FURTHER CLARIFICATION: I would only need to perform this rearrangement of the string if the group of numbers was 3 digits or less, because the zip code will frequently come after the address suffix, and in cases like that I wouldn't want to rearrange the string.

Comment: Why do you truncate at all? What comes after the street name? Maybe its easier to truncate by some other metric. Show some example of your street names, including what comes after. Are you talking about structured data, or are you parsing unstructured data, such as texts and websites?

Comment: I am using geopy to geocode and clean my addresses further. Geopy doesn't do much cleaning. It will only make slight changes such as super simple typos or formatting. That is why I have to do the majority of the cleaning prior to passing it to geopy. There are a wide variety of things that come after the street suffix. In almost 100% of these situations, the stuff that comes after the suffix isn't important. I am getting the best results out of Geopy when I pass it the closest thing to a perfect address.

Comment: Further clarification. I work for a company that does international shipping, and the address quality is atrocious. People who live outside of the US don't always understand the US address format, not to mention New York City is even more difficult. So i'm taking their raw addresses and putting them in the best shape that I can, and then geocoding them.

Comment: "People who live outside of the US don't always understand the US address format" Well, people who live outside the US do not _use_ the US address format. Streets could have different suffixes, such as `Straße` or other funky stuff, zip codes have different number of digits, etc. What I wanted to say: Whatever rule you have, it's probably wrong for one case or another.

Comment: I know. I totally undestand. The company also has immense problems with people in the US shipping things outside of the US. I didn't mean any disrespect by it, i'm sorry if I made it seem like that. I'm also working on another project with Saudi Arabian addresses and they're night and day different from US. I just need to try and clean these addresses to the best of my ability. I'm at roughly 94% accuracy. I'm just making baby steps to slowly inch that number up.

Comment: have you tried regex with look-ahead  or positive lookbehind assertion? you've already idntified avenue so I suppose it might work

Comment: Hmm. I'm not the best with regex. I have a few simple regex filters in this script but they're not too advanced. How do you think I could go about doing that?

Comment: I posted an answer, it's positive lookbehind assertion, it might be helpful. More on regex for instance here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: If you're dealing with US addresses - you should probably just check out https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps, but you can start with this:

```
import re
address = '7TH AVENUE 530 xxxxxxxxxxx'
m = re.search('(?<=AVENUE )\d{1,3}', address)
print (m.group(0))
>>> 530
```

Edit based on your comment:

```
import re
original = '7TH AVENUE 530 xxxxxxxxxxx'
patterns = ['street', 'avenue', 'road', 'place']
regex = r'(.*)(' + '|'.join(patterns) + r')(.*)'
address = re.sub(regex, r'\1\2', original.lower()).lstrip()
new_addr = re.search(r'(?<=%s )\d{1,3} ' % address, original.lower())
resulting_address = ' '.join([new_addr.group(0).strip(),address]) if new_addr else address
address = ' '.join(map(str.capitalize, resulting_address.split()))
```

Comment: How could i append this to work for not just avenue, but my list of suffixed (called patterns). And then how would i append the 530 to the front? Sorry i'm not the best with regex.

Comment: Here's what i'm currently doing in terms of regex to locate the pattern and remove everything after it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/22318974/

Comment: please see my edit, `original` is the original string and adress is identifier you already found using your regex. I hope this will help you.

Comment: So would I put your two lines under the two regex lines that I already have? I would also prefer to keep the address named 'address'. Also, I don't think that address is the identifier, is it? In my code that I showed you address is the resulting address after removing everything after the suffix.

Comment: yes, actually 3 lines - I added capitalization at the very end. You can avoid it if you find more clever way to discover pattern without using `.lower()`, see the current edit

Comment: I'm having quite a few issues implementing that. Hold on.

Comment: sorry, missing parenthesis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120254/discussion-between-hleggs-and-juraj-bezrucka).